# 等間隔なtextboxのForeColorの変更

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

プログラミング初心者です。

visual studio2012を使用し、textbox5～9に矢印を表示し、表示された順番にボタンを押す脳トレゲームを作りたいと考えています。

timerを使用し、等間隔にtextboxの前景色をwhiteからblackに変える処理を実行するため、以下のように入力したのですが、どうしても一度で処理が行われてしまいます。

```
Do Until (TextBox5.ForeColor = Color.Black) And (TextBox6.ForeColor = Color.Black) And (TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Black) And (TextBox8.ForeColor = Color.Black)
            Timer1.Enabled = True
            TextBox5.ForeColor = Color.Black
            TextBox6.ForeColor = Color.Black
            TextBox7.ForeColor = Color.Black
            TextBox8.ForeColor = Color.Black
        Loop
        Timer1.Enabled = False
```

これだけでは無理だということはわかるのですが、どうすれば等間隔に色が変わるのかがわかりません。

ほかにも、処理の部分にor文を使用(当然実行もされませんでした)、「もしtextbox5~9がwhiteなら」というif文に変更するなど、思いつく限り実行したのですが、現状は変わらずです。

timerの使い方等が間違っているのかとも思いましたが、エラーは一切出ておらず、検索しても参考になるものが見当たらなかったため、投稿させていただきました。
至らぬ点ばかりだとは思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

やりたいことは下記のサンプルコードのような処理でしょうか。
タイマーは`Tick`イベントに書かれた処理を等間隔のタイミングで実行します。
`Do Until`のループでは中に書かれている処理を一気に行いますので、質問にある動作となります。

`If`文の`And`や`Or`の使い方、そしてタイマーの使い方、プロシージャの処理について、学習した内容が多くて混乱しているのかも知れませんね。
実装したい全ての機能をまとめて追加するよりも、少しずつコードを加えて動作を確認しながら機能を追加していく方が、開発や理解の速度が上がると思います。

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'タイマー開始
        Timer1.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim textCursors = New TextBox() {TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8} '色を変えるカーソル用テキストボックスの配列
        'TextBox5～TextBox8の文字色を順番にチェックし、文字色が黒くない先頭の項目を変更する
        For Each textBox In textCursors
            If textBox.ForeColor <> Color.Black Then
                textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        '全てのテキストボックスについて色を変え終わったらタイマー終了
        If textCursors.Last.ForeColor = Color.Black Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```